# Disable all UIPanGestureRecognizers after `touchesBegan:withEvent:`

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiresponder

Is there a way to disable all of the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`s that a touch effects? I am hoping to be able to isolate all touch events to one of my subviews and have every superview ignore all the touch events, but I can only determine this after `touchesBegan:withEvent:`.

Is it possible to stop my superview's `UIPanGestureRecognizer`s from interacting with a touch after it has triggered `touchesBegan:withEvent:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable and re-enable panning in all superviews, you should do something like this:

```
- (void)recursivelyEnable:(BOOL)enable panGesturesInSuperview:(UIView *)superview
{
    for(UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer in superview.gestureRecognizers)
    {
        if([superview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])[(UIScrollView *)superview setScrollEnabled:enable];
        else [recognizer setEnabled:enable];
    }
    if(superview.superview)[self recursivelyEnable:enable panGesturesInSuperview:superview.superview];
}
```

and use it like so:

```
//Disable panning
[self recursivelyEnable:NO panGesturesInSuperview:self.superview];

//Enable panning
[self recursivelyEnable:YES panGesturesInSuperview:self.superview];
```

For some reason, you can't mess around with the `UIGestureRecognizer`s of a `UIScrollView` or any of it's subclasses; that is why I've included the check and alternative dis/enabling of panning.

Answer (score 1):

Yes use this code:

```
yourGesture.enabled = NO;
```

Comment: Actually, I was mistaken. It does actually work. I, stupidly, called the wrong method.

Comment: Oh. I don't know why I didn't look for an "enabled" property. Let me see if it works after the touch, as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33312/discussion-between-rileye-and-abdullah-shafique)